# JNI: How can I pass a TreeMap from Java to C++

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

How can I pass a TreeMap - Map< String, int[ ] > treeMap - from Java to C++ via JNI ?

At the moment I pass a String array ( = keys) from Java to C++ and initialize a map  - std::map< std::string, std::vector > myMapVector - in C++. 
In a second method I pass a string = key and an int array from Java and fill the vector in my previously created map.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the TreeMap and use it directly:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html#wp1253

Comment: Thanks. So you advise accessing the Java object (= myMap) directly?

Comment: It's probably the most efficient approach since you avoid rebuilding the tree.

Comment: I managed to realize your solution. I am able to access the Java HashMap field. To work with my HashMap I have to build my "interface" to the java/util/HashMap class.  Then I can use the get method  of the java/util/HashMap class via JNI.  But what to you think - am I faster when I call a getter-method from JNI with a jstring as parameter, which I use as my key for the HashMap. Then lets Java do the work and then return a jintarray.